# How To Connect Two Monitors To Lenovo 320 ideapad

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, usb-c

I want to connect two monitors to my lenovo ideapad 320 laptop. It has one HDMI port, 2 USB 2.0 and one USB-C port. Is there any way where I can connect two monitors to it along with keyboard and mouse? Also the display should be in **extended** mode and not **duplicate** so that each display should be independent of the other.

Answer (score 2):

In the [user manual](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1041267260.pdf), on page 7, it reads:

> Type-C port support:
>
> - USB 3.1 Gen1

That means your USB-C port *does not* support DisplayPort display connections but only USB data connections.

Unlike DisplayPort, HDMI only supports a single display.

This leaves the following options for the second external display:

- A USB graphics solution, like Artur Ludwik linked to in his answer (“DisplayLink”)
- A Matrix DualHead2Go for use with DVI (doesn’t support all of HDMI, but should be sufficient)

When considering a USB graphics solution, look for USB 3.0 (USB 3.1 Gen1 is USB 3.0) for ideal performance. However, be very careful: You probably won’t find one with USB-C that isn’t dependent on DisplayPort Alt Mode. Instead, you may have to get an additional USB-C-USB-A adapter.

And then, of course, there’s also USB hubs, if you need more ports.

Answer (score 0):

propably you need to use a external adapter, sth like this: https://m.newegg.ca/products/N82E16812400524

Comment: I have only 2 USB ports which I want to use for keyboard and mouse. Is it possible to use HDMI and USB-C port for connecting monitors?

Comment: Yep, it is possible, below similar adapter for usb-c, https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32950504089.html?src=google&albslr=230412451&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=494-037-6276&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&gclsrc=aw.ds&&albagn=888888&albcp=1705845725&albag=70384466841&trgt=296904914040&crea=pl32950504089&netw=g&device=m&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgrmImczA4AIVVOh3Ch256gl5EAQYASABEgJ0lPD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel B has clarified, you can't just plug in any monitor into your USB-C port, as it doesn't support Display Port.

There are however some screens that will work through any USB 3.0 connector using a vendor-specific driver. One of them is the [Asus ZenScreen](https://www.asus.com/Displays-Desktops/Monitors/ZenScreen/ZenScreen-MB16ACM/), which will even connect to a USB-A 3.0 port:

> [The Zen Screen] only requires a single USB connection for both power and video transmission from your host device. It features an innovative hybrid-signal solution with native support for USB Type-C™ (USB-C™) connections, and uses an installed driver to support USB Type-A connectors for full compatibility.

So you probably can even connect some USB-Hub to your USB-C port, attach the Zen screen to that and gain some free ports for other peripherals.

There might be other devices on the market that work in a similar way Be sure to contact the OEM before buying, to make sure the product is compatible with your device.

*FULL DISCLOSURE: I own an Asus Zen Screen. I don't have any business association whatever with Asus, nor do I own stock or any other interest in that company. This answer is not meant in any way to recommend a spicific product over any other possible product, but only to give the OP a possible solution to his question.*

Answer (score -2):

There's **a splitter** you can buy. So, you can connect your both monitors in it and the output in the laptop.

***Check this one***

[HDMI Male to Dual HDMI Female 1 to 2 Way HDMI Splitter Adapter Cable with USB Power Cable for HDTV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JLRLW53)

Comment: “Also the display should be in extended mode and not duplicate”, so no.